# CardView and RecyclerViews on kitkat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am planning to use `CardView` and `RecyclerView` in my current application replacing the `GridView`. However, these views (`CardView` and `RecyclerView`) are supported on `Lollipop (5.0)` and onwards.

I wonder, what would happened if a user has operating system lower than `Lollipop`, like `Kitkat`?

How could I support that devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are part of `Android Support libraries` v7. You can use them by adding following support libraries in your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

And you can define a `RecyclerView` from `Support Library`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

For more, take a look at official guidelines:

http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 1):

they come as a part of "support" or "compat" packages, so both components should be available also in pre-kitkat versions